# how to rearrange data and repeat column name within rows of dataframe in R?

Tags: r

How can I rearrange columns and rows while also repeating column names for the length of the column?

Is there a way to make a data frame that looks like this...

[image]

Into this...

[image]

Edit:

Starting data...

```
df <- structure(list(patient_ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    PK_day = c("pk1", "pk1", "pk1", "pk1", "pk2", "pk2", "pk2", 
    "pk2"), record_id = c("pk1_bsin_blood_time", "pk1_drug_admin_time", 
    "pk1_15_blood_time", "pk1_30_blood_time", "pk2_bsIn_blood_time", 
    "pk2_drug_admin_time", "pk2_15_blood_time", "pk2_30_blood_time"
    ), UGPK1001 = c("9:45", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "9:40", 
    "10:20", "10:38", "10:50"), hh.mm = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), UGPK1004 = c("9:45", "10:25", "10:40", "10:55", 
    "10:15", NA, NA, NA), hh.mm.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    NA, NA), UGPK1007 = c("10:55", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", 
    "10:00", "10:40", "10:55", "11:10"), hh.mm.2 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Please consider to provide small reproducible example using `dput` instead of images so that it can be tested

Comment: This question is not clear. Most unclear is the missing data in `UGPK1004` in wide format that occur in long format. What is the logic behind  etc... Please clarify!

Comment: I added the starting data code as recommended. The data is "missing" for ID 1004 because only some time points were taken.

Comment: @jc2525 Thank you. And could you please explain what is wrong with my solution provided here, so maybe we could improve!

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work. Stupid me misspelled things. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it this way.
It remains unclear with the NA time which I removed with  `filter(!is.na(Actual_time))`
If we know how they are generated in the long format then just remove the filter and add to the dataset!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(-patient_ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(UGPK1001, UGPK1004, UGPK1007), 
    names_to = "patient_ID",
    values_to = "Actual_time"
  ) %>% 
  arrange(patient_ID) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Actual_time)) %>% 
  select(patient_ID, PK_day, record_id, Actual_time, `hh:mm`=hh.mm)
```

```
   patient_ID PK_day           record_id Actual_time hh:mm
1    UGPK1001    pk1 pk1_bsin_blood_time        9:45     0
2    UGPK1001    pk1 pk1_drug_admin_time       10:30     0
3    UGPK1001    pk1   pk1_15_blood_time       10:45     0
4    UGPK1001    pk1   pk1_30_blood_time       11:00     0
5    UGPK1001    pk2 pk2_bsIn_blood_time        9:40     0
6    UGPK1001    pk2 pk2_drug_admin_time       10:20     0
7    UGPK1001    pk2   pk2_15_blood_time       10:38     0
8    UGPK1001    pk2   pk2_30_blood_time       10:50     0
9    UGPK1004    pk1 pk1_bsin_blood_time        9:45     0
10   UGPK1004    pk1 pk1_drug_admin_time       10:25     0
11   UGPK1004    pk1   pk1_15_blood_time       10:40     0
12   UGPK1004    pk1   pk1_30_blood_time       10:55     0
13   UGPK1004    pk2 pk2_bsIn_blood_time       10:15     0
14   UGPK1007    pk1 pk1_bsin_blood_time       10:55     0
15   UGPK1007    pk1 pk1_drug_admin_time       11:30     0
16   UGPK1007    pk1   pk1_15_blood_time       11:45     0
17   UGPK1007    pk1   pk1_30_blood_time       12:00     0
18   UGPK1007    pk2 pk2_bsIn_blood_time       10:00     0
19   UGPK1007    pk2 pk2_drug_admin_time       10:40     0
20   UGPK1007    pk2   pk2_15_blood_time       10:55     0
21   UGPK1007    pk2   pk2_30_blood_time       11:10     0
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(patient_ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    PK_day = c("pk1", "pk1", "pk1", "pk1", "pk2", "pk2", "pk2", 
    "pk2"), record_id = c("pk1_bsin_blood_time", "pk1_drug_admin_time", 
    "pk1_15_blood_time", "pk1_30_blood_time", "pk2_bsIn_blood_time", 
    "pk2_drug_admin_time", "pk2_15_blood_time", "pk2_30_blood_time"
    ), UGPK1001 = c("9:45", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "9:40", 
    "10:20", "10:38", "10:50"), hh.mm = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), UGPK1004 = c("9:45", "10:25", "10:40", "10:55", 
    "10:15", NA, NA, NA), hh.mm.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    NA, NA), UGPK1007 = c("10:55", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", 
    "10:00", "10:40", "10:55", "11:10"), hh.mm.2 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```